# Why was this edit rejected by Community?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3653853

I made last code block visible, I didn't add anything that wasn't already in a post. Just the lack of newline rendered it hidden. And I removed "thank-you" part. It was approved by one reviewer, and then rejected by community, apparently without any other edit.

It's been a long time since I suggested edits (I'm mostly on Drupal Answers where I'm 10k+ already), so I admit I have no clue how it works now.

Comment: Maybe because while the suggested edit was awaiting review, another user with edit privileges made an edit to the same post. It is an auto-rejection in this case.

Comment: @AzizShaikh if so, then he failed to make last code block visible and to remove thank you - pretty bad job on his part ;) Should I suggest edit again? Edit: someone just fixed it anyway.

Comment: Sure why not. Goal is to improve the post/content.

Comment: @AzizShaikh is correct, this is typical edit conflict. The user samitha started editing before the edit was suggested, and submitted his edit while the suggested edit was still pending resulting in its automatic rejection. It happens **a lot**, but luckily a recent change made it that such rejections won't cause edit ban to those suggesting the edits. :)